# mjpg трансляция

Tags: php, mjpg

Хочу транслировать изображение с вебкамеры на сайте. Камера находится в локалке с сервером по внутреннему адресу 192.168.х.х. Так же вебсервер доступен по-внешнему адресу mysite.ru с выделенным айпи адресом. Как транслировать камеру на сайте по адресу mysite.ru, если камера находится во внутренней сетке, к которому сервер имеет доступ?

Я делал:

img.php

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.100/video/mjpg.cgi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

если вставить в index.php

```
<img src="/img.php">
```

то ничего не показывается. то есть грузится долго (это же поток!!) и обрывается в итоге ничего нет. Как еще можно транслировать из внутренней сети во внешнюю?

**UPD.**

камерами управляет TrendNET TV-IP512P. Сервер под управлением Win 2K3. Веб-сервер - денвер.

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в сторону протокола [WebRTC][1]. Пока стандарт имеет пометку [Draft][2], но думаю, в спецификацию HTML 5.1 войдёт как RFC.

Видео-поток (формат WebM) транслируется между клиентами, минуя сервер (P2P). Через сервер же, проходят лишь служебные данные о соединении клиентов.
Для продакшена, думаю рановато, хотя проекты уже имеются (sipml5, Callbacker).

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/163527/
  [2]: http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html

Answer (score 1):

Делать ретранслятор на php - гиблое дело. Был бы mjpeg поток, что-нибудь бы намутил. А так можно и уже готовыми программами воспользоваться: http://www.nchsoftware.com/broadcam/index.html и бесплатная и работает годно.

Comment: Так поток как раз таки mjpeg...  Что можно намутить??

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай я имею ввиду существующий поток, который можно захватить.

Answer (score 1):

1. можно транслировать с WEB камеры, используя модуль [ngx_rtmp_module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module), подробная [статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/162237/), как это использовать
2. можно использовать [медиасервер](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114560/) Максима Лапшина erlvideo
3. или медиасервер [red5](http://www.red5.org/)

в любом случае, советую использовать специально разработанный для трансляции софт